# Query does not show expected result

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'll try to be as specific as i can here, so here's the query using MsAccess.

```
SELECT MsThread.ID, 
       MsThread.ThreadName, 
COUNT(MsThread.ThreadName) AS TotalPost 
FROM MsThread 
LEFT OUTER JOIN MsPosts 
ON MsThread.ThreadName = MsPosts.ThreadName 
GROUP BY MsThread.ID, MsThread.ThreadName, MsThread.ThreadCategory
```

When I ran the query in MsAccess it returns this:[image]

It shows that I have 4 rows ( # of threads ), and the number 5,2,1,1 is the number of posts with specified threads. Here I've been trying to get the resultset to return 4 instead of 9 so I can loop it without no invalid cursor state error.

```
rs.last();
int row = rs.getRow();
```

that returns 8, so i am guessing its returning how many process thats done. so how do i get it to return 4 similar to the COUNT function?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Just so you're aware, the rows returning `TotalPost = 1` are _not_ guaranteed to actually have a row.  Your use of `LEFT JOIN` means that rows in `MsPosts` aren't required, so if there isn't a row it just counts the single row in `MsThread`.  I also doubt that that's the query you're running, giving that `threadcategory` is shown in your results, but the column isn't part of your `SELECT` list.

Answer (score 0):

rs, I'm assuming, is the resultant recordset that your SQL returns?  If so, you can do:

```
rs.MoveFirst
rs.MoveLast

X = rs.RecordCount
```

X should equal 4 in this case, since you have 4 records in your recordset.

I don't think you want to use "row" as a variable name, as that is a reserved word and will probably cause issues when you try to reference it.  Make your life easier and call it "RowX" or something that's not reserved.

Comment: Hey how do you do so in JSP? I can't use MoveFirst and MoveLast.

Comment: This question was tagged with MS Access and SQL.  You should edit ti and tag it with JSP, I don't know that language at all.  Sorry.  :o(